# C# parse XML file to object

Tags: c#, xml

Using C#, is there a way to easily parse an XML file so that it can be used as an object?

Example XML:

```xml
<Config>
    <Ui>
        <Colour>black</Colour>
        <Size>small</Size>
    </Ui>
    <Output>
        <Mode>smb</Mode>
        <Version>2</Version>
    </Output>
</Config>
```

And then refer to the parameters in my application by

```
Config.Output.Mode
```

I've tried this method - [How to Deserialize XML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document)

But when I try

```
var cfg = new Config();
cfg.Load(@"config.xml");
Console.WriteLine(cfg.Output.Mode);
```

visual studio indicates .Output.Mode is not valid.

Where Config.Load is

```cs
xmlData = File.ReadAllText(configPath);
    
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Config));
    
using (var reader = new StringReader(xmlData))
{
    Config result = (Config)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Comment: *it doesn't work* - what it gives you? an error? null? could you post your code for reference?

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* you have neither shown us your code, or error, i would consider reading the help on stack overflow. [ask]

Comment: Can you share the exact error message you are getting from Visual studio? Also the code of Config, Output and Mode?

Comment: Well, that's close, but what do you do with `result`? Because that's your deserialized `Config` object. Not `cfg`...

Comment: "visual studio indicates .Output.Mode is not valid." - could you please clarify how that relates to XML or serialization? You may want to re-read [mcve] guidance and [edit] post to clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the classes:

```
public class Config
{
    public UI UI { get; set; }
    public Output Output { get; set; }
}

public struct UI
{
    public string Colour { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
}

public struct Output
{
    public string Mode { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
}
```

The Deserialize function:

```
    public static T Deserialize<T>(string xmlString)
    {
        if (xmlString == null) return default;
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (var reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
        {
            return (T) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
```

And here's a working version:

```
        Config cfg = Deserialize<Config>(xmlString);
        Console.WriteLine(cfg.Output.Mode);
```

Comment: What if I have more than one <output> element? How could I deserialize this to that it could be referred to by cfg.Output[0].Mode ?

Answer (score 6):

You have to create the classes that match the definition in the xml file in order to deserialize the file into an instance of the class. Note that I've named the properties with the same name as we have in the xml file. If you want to use different property names, then you'd need to add an attribute above the property that specifies the xml element that should map to it (like for the `Ui`, you would add the attribute: `[XmlElement("Ui")])`.

Note that I've also overridden the `ToString` methods for the classes so we can output them to the console in a nice fashion:

```
public class Config
{
    public UI Ui { get; set; }
    public Output Output { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Config has properties:\n - Ui: {Ui}\n - Output: {Output}";
    }
}

public class UI
{
    public string Colour { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"(Colour: {Colour}, Size: {Size})";
    }
}

public class Output
{
    public string Mode { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"(Mode: {Mode}, Version: {Version})";
    }
}
```

Now all we have to do is create a `StreamReader`, point it to our file path, and then use the `XmlSerializer` class to `Deserialize` the file (casting the output to the appropriate type) into an object:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var filePath = @"f:\private\temp\temp2.txt";

    // Declare this outside the 'using' block so we can access it later
    Config config;

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        config = (Config) new XmlSerializer(typeof(Config)).Deserialize(reader);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(config);

    GetKeyFromUser("\n\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]